# Error with usin Apache POI

Tags: java, apache, exception

I have created a search tool to search word documents in a selected folder for a given keyword and return the filenames that contain the keyword. The error is possibly due to Apache I have used Apache POI in order to read word documents however i get the following error when I compile the project:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:140)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Field.java:949)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:930)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:372)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.typeSystemForClassLoader(XmlBeans.java:770)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.DocumentDocument.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.DocumentDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.onDocumentRead(XWPFDocument.java:135)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:159)
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.<init>(XWPFDocument.java:124)
    at Main.jButton1ActionPerformed(Main.java:176)
    at Main.access$000(Main.java:27)
    at Main$1.actionPerformed(Main.java:78)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6504)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6269)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not instantiate SchemaTypeSystemImpl (java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException): is the version of xbean.jar correct?
    at schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sE130CAA0A01A7CDE5A2B4FEB8B311707.TypeSystemHolder.loadTypeSystem(Unknown Source)
    at schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sE130CAA0A01A7CDE5A2B4FEB8B311707.TypeSystemHolder.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaTypeLoaderException: XML-BEANS compiled schema: Incompatible minor version - expecting up to 23, got 24 (schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sE130CAA0A01A7CDE5A2B4FEB8B311707.index) - code 3
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl$XsbReader.<init>(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:1522)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl.initFromHeader(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:260)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl.<init>(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:183)
    ... 57 more
```

The complete code is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.filechooser.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.extractor.XWPFWordExtractor;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/*
 * Main.java
 *
 * Created on Jul 4, 2014, 8:19:21 AM
 */
/**
 *
 * @author Yağız
 */
public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Boolean check = true;
    File[] filelist;
    /** Creates new form Main */
    public Main() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {
        bindingGroup = new org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup();

        jFrame1 = new javax.swing.JFrame();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        label1 = new java.awt.Label();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jFrame1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jFrame1.getContentPane());
        jFrame1.getContentPane().setLayout(jFrame1Layout);
        jFrame1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jFrame1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jMenu1.setText("File");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        jMenu2.setText("Edit");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, jFrame1, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("CV Search"), this, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("title"));
        bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

        label1.setText("Keyword:");

        jButton1.setText("Find");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Select Folder");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton2)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 56, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(label1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 140, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGap(29, 29, 29))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(label1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addComponent(jButton1))
                .addGap(37, 37, 37))
        );

        bindingGroup.bind();

        java.awt.Dimension screenSize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setBounds((screenSize.width-278)/2, (screenSize.height-158)/2, 278, 158);
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        //Select Folder Button
        try{
            JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
            fc.showOpenDialog(null);
            if(fc.getSelectedFile()==null){
                check = false;
            } 
            else 
            {
                File folder = new File(fc.getSelectedFile().getPath());
                filelist = folder.listFiles();
                if( filelist.length == 0 ){
                // dialog: folder is empty
                    check = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    check = true;
                }
             }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
        }
    }                                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        //Find button for finding the word in word documents in the selected folder   
        String keyword = jTextField1.getText();
        int count=0;

        while (! check ) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select a Folder!");
            return;
        }

        if(keyword.equals("")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No keyword found!");
            return;
        }

        ArrayList result = new ArrayList();

        try
        {
            for( int i=0; i < filelist.length; i++){
                // maybe also .doc?
                if( !filelist[i].getName().endsWith( ".docx" ) ) continue;
                count++;
                //...
                XWPFDocument input = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(filelist[i]));
                XWPFWordExtractor extract = new XWPFWordExtractor(input);
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(extract.getText());
                while(scan.hasNext())
                {
                    String word = scan.next();
                    if( keyword.equals(word) ) {
                        result.add(filelist[i].getName());
                    break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if( count == 0 ){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please select a valid document");
                return;
            }

            //...
            if(result.isEmpty()){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No match found!");
                return;
            }
            else {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for( int j = 0; j < result.size(); j++){
                    sb.append( result.get(j) ).append( "\n" );
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, sb.toString() );
            }              
        } catch (Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error!");
        }
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new Main().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JFrame jFrame1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private java.awt.Label label1;
    private org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup bindingGroup;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Finally here are the .jar files I have added to project:

```
poi-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
poi-examples-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
poi-excelant-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
poi-ooxml-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
poi-scratchpad-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
xmlbenas-2.2.0.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
ooxml-schemas-1.0.jar
```

Why am I getting this error?

edit: didn't have xbeans 2.20 in my project which has the same version with xmlbeans but still get the error when i added xbean.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding one more Jar - `stax-api-1.0.1.jar` which is inside `ooxml-lib`. Also

```
XML-BEANS compiled schema: Incompatible minor version - expecting up to 23, got 24 (schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sE130CAA0A01A7CDE5A2B4FEB8B311707.index) - code 3
```

It shows there is version mismatch.

Putting both xmlbean and xbean of same version should solve the issue.

Comment: Keep xmlbean and xbean of same version

Comment: i didn't have any xbean.jar file in the library. now i have added xbean.jar 2.20 which has the same version with xmlbeans. It gives the same error again

Comment: Update your exception in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
List of jar file to download
these files are present in poi-bin source library
1>>poi-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
2>>poi-examples-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
3>>poi-excelant-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
4>>poi-ooxml-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
5>>poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
6>>poi-scratchpad-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
7>>dom4j-1.6.1.jar
8>>ooxml-schemas-1.0.jar
new JAR FILE 
xmlbeans-2.4.0.jar/[use in place of xmlbeam2.4.0.jar or higher version]
use 
this jar file enough for docx and doc file 

-------------------HERE IS CODE------------------------
package com.adastara.docx;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.extractor.XWPFWordExtractor;
import java.io.*;

public class ReadDocx
{
public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception {
 /* XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument();
  XWPFWordExtractor we = new XWPFWordExtractor(docx);
  System.out.println(we.getText());*/
    System.out.println("--MAIN---");    
    XWPFDocument doc = null;
    FileInputStream fis=null;
    try {

        fis = new FileInputStream("PATH OR LOCATION OF FILE(may be DOC / DOCX / PDF) ");
        doc = new XWPFDocument(fis);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {   e.printStackTrace();
    }
    XWPFWordExtractor extractor = null;
    extractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(doc);
    String s = extractor.getText();
    System.out.println(s);
    try {
        extractor.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Comment: Maybe you could clarify a bit what you are doing instead of just dumping a lot of code? Thanks!